# Scale the image for a map overlay - google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, itemizedoverlay

I followed the tutorial for map overlays that Google offers (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) and it works fine, except the image for the overlay doesn't scale when you zoom in and out. I have Maps zoomed in on a city, and I want to put markets on several of the buildings, but the overlay image doesn't scale when it zooms in. Is there a way to have the overlay image scale up and down as users zoom in and out?

I have seen the answer where they used vector circles as the points on the map. That wont work for me, because I need to use custom images as the point on my map.

If you want to see my code, I can post it, but it is the exact the same as the example, except for some variable name changes.